# Manipulate with dependent values

Tags: manipulate

Sorry for possible duplicate. Is it possible to bind dynamically to variables of Manipulate, so if I change one variable the second one changes synchronously in the following example

```
Manipulate[
 {a, b, c},
 {a, 0, 10},
 {b, 0, 10},
 {c, 0, 10},
 {{equalab, false, "a=b"}, { true, false}},
 {{equalbc, false, "c=b"}, { true, false}},
 {{equalac, false, "a=c"}, { true, false}}
]
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
Manipulate[If[equalab, b = a]; If[equalbc, c = b]; If[equalac, c = a]; {a, b, c}, 
 {a, 0, 10}, {b, 0, 10}, {c, 0,  10}, 
 {{equalab, False, "a=b"}, {True, False}}, 
 {{equalbc, False, "c=b"}, {True, False}}, 
 {{equalac, False, "a=c"}, {True, False}}]
```

[image]